# How to force “Windows Explorer” to open new folders in the same window

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I have been searching for an answer to this question for a very long time. I have checked the "open folders in the same window" radio button in the general tab of folder options. I have also been told to uncheck the launch as seperate processes button in the view tab of folder options.

Actually it was working fine. I did modification in folder options like, TOOLS -> folder options -> File type -> File folder -> advance -> new -> and I added cygwin and its path after this only I am facing this problem. Now I have no clue how to rectify this problem.

I am using windows XP professional, service pack 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FIX: Open each folder in the same window](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/samewindow.htm)

> **Symptom**
>
> When you double-click a drive or
>   folder in My Computer or Windows
>   Explorer in a Windows XP computer, it
>   may open in a new window.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Open Control Panel, double-click
>   Folder Options and select the General
>   tab. Select the Open each folder in
>   the same window option and click OK.
>
> If that does not correct the problem,
>   then this may be due to incorrect
>   settings in the registry. This can
>   easily be fixed using the REG file
>   below. Download
>   [samefolderwindow.reg](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/reg/samefolderwindow.reg) (for Windows
>   XP only) and save to Desktop.
>   Right-click the file and then choose
>   Merge.

Answer (score 0):

That should work as you expect. These are the default options (at least on XP Pro).

Have you tried closing all the Explorer windows and then opening a new one? Double check that the settings have "stuck".

Are you part of a domain? It could be that group policy is resetting these options each time.

Comment: I have checked all these options and rebooted my system also. I am using windows XP professional, service pack 3.

Comment: @Thangaraj - do you have a custom mouse driver installed? I can't see how that would affect this behaviour, but you never know.

Comment: I guess it is default configuration right if I am not wrong.